# How to save the position of an element after dragging and changing its position in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I used the kanban library for Drag and Drop and now I want their location to be saved after dragging and dropping. After the page is refreshed, they should be in the saved position

**I have not tried the cookie yet**.
What do you guys suggest?
Thansk for your help

````
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Board, { moveCard } from "@lourenci/react-kanban";
import "@lourenci/react-kanban/dist/styles.css";

function ControlledBoard() {
    // You need to control the state yourself.
    const [controlledBoard, setBoard] = useState(board);

    function handleCardMove(_card, source, destination) {
        const updatedBoard = moveCard(controlledBoard, source, destination);
        setBoard(updatedBoard);
    }

    return (
        <Board onCardDragEnd={handleCardMove} disableColumnDrag>
            {controlledBoard}
        </Board>
    );
}

function UncontrolledBoard() {
    return (
        <>
        <Board
            allowRemoveLane
            allowRenameColumn
            disableColumnDrag
            allowRemoveCard
            onLaneRemove={console.log}
            onCardRemove={console.log}
            onLaneRename={console.log}
            initialBoard={board}
            allowAddCard
            onNewCardConfirm={draftCard => ({
                id: new Date().getTime(),
                ...draftCard
            })}
            onCardNew={console.log}
        />
        </>
    );
}

function App() {
    return (
        <>
            <h4>Example of an uncontrolled board</h4>
            <UncontrolledBoard />
            <h4>Example of a controlled board</h4>
            <p>Just the card moving is implemented in this demo.</p>
            <p>
                In this kind of board, you can do whatever you want. We just mirror your
                board state.
            </p>
            <ControlledBoard />
        </>
    );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);```
````

Comment: I think the best way would be to create you backend API with database where you could save your data. If you don't wish to do this way, you need to store this value somewhere on the client side. Although you could store you value inside the cookie (or even URL's query string), it's probably not the best way to store the data. You can look at [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) which stores the data on the client side (so be careful not to save any sensitive data there!)

Answer (score 0):

Storing the location of each instance, as an object with source and destination, in localStorage can solve the issue

```
localStorage.setItem(
      `instance`,
      JSON.stringify({
        board: {
           source: value,
           destination:value
        },
      })
    );
```

Comment: Can you show me how to do it?

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please check if that helps

Comment: I'm new to react so i don't know what should i put instead of  value                can you help me with that?

Comment: the source and destination values would be same as you have passed in moveCard

Comment: Where should I put it?